# jQuery copy text from span tag to another span tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here's what I'm trying to do(slider):[Image screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3YM0.png)

I'm trying to copy the test from the span that has the class of .panel-title to the span with the class of .duplicate-test.

My HTML code is

```
<div class="item">
  <a href="./">
   <div class="panel-img">
    <img src="_assets_/images/panel-event.png" alt="">
   </div><!-- /.panel-img -->
   <div class="panel-info">
    <div><p class="duplicate-test"></p></div>
    <span class="panel-title">upcoming events</span>
   </div><!-- /.panel-info -->
  </a>
</div><!-- /.item -->
```

My jQuery code is

```
$('.duplicate-test').text($(this).find('.panel-title').text());
```

It is getting the text from all spans with the class of .panel-title. Is there something wrong with my jQuery code?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('.duplicate-test').each(function() {
    $(this).text($(this).parent().next('.panel-title').text());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with your DOM traversal and usage of `this`.

Assuming there's no outer scope of the snippet you've shown, `this` will refer to the `window`, not the current `.duplicate-test` element. To do what you require, you need to pass the `text()` method a function. From there you can traverse to find the element you want:

```
$('.duplicate-test').text(function() {
    return $(this).closest('.panel-info').find('.panel-title').text();
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/n5qvwsgr/)